# Unable to build GNU automake

Tags: unix, gnu, automake

Installed automake using `wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/automake/automake-1.15.tar.gz`

`./configure --prefix=$HOME/local` works fine for me.

After this step, I ran `make` and it fails:

```
  GEN      bin/automake
  GEN      bin/aclocal
  GEN      t/ax/shell-no-trail-bslash
  GEN      t/ax/cc-no-c-o
  GEN      runtest
  GEN      lib/Automake/Config.pm
  GEN      doc/aclocal-1.15.1
  GEN      doc/automake-1.15.1
help2man: can't get `--help' info from automake-1.15
Try `--no-discard-stderr' if option outputs to stderr
make: *** [doc/automake-1.15.1] Error 2
```

I do not know how to proceed!

Another thing is I try to run `bin/aclocal` and it says:

```
Can't locate Automake/Config.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /home/v/varun/local/share/automake-1.15 /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at bin/aclocal line 37.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at bin/aclocal line 37.
```

Please help!

Do you need any other questions?

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, you must either downgrade your `Perl` version, or update the version of `automake` that you're trying to build:

The `help2man` program tries to run `automake-1.15 --help`. If this fails, then you will see the error above. In my case, the original failure looked like this:

```
$ ./1.15-r0/build/t/wrap/automake-1.15 --help
Unescaped left brace in regex is illegal here in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\${ <-- HERE ([^ \t=:+{}]+)}/ at /home/user/proj/yocto/test/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.15-r0/build/bin/automake line 3939.
Compilation failed in require at ./1.15-r0/build/t/wrap/automake-1.15 line 27.
```

This is caused by an incompatibility between automake version 1.15 and a too recent Perl version (see [this bug](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-automake/2017-06/msg00003.html)).

Comment: I am installing automake-1.16 and encounted the same problem. I cannot use the GIT version because my autoreconf does not work (requires aclocal ...) My perl version is quite old: v5.16.3 (Copyright 1987-2012)

Comment: Update: by copying doc/help2man from GIT to 1.16 version I was able to make and make install.

Answer (score 1):

`perl-Thread-Queue.noarch` needed;

if your os is [centos](/questions/tagged/centos), try this:

```
yum install perl-Thread-Queue.noarch
```

Comment: I got a similar error on Debian testing and installing libthread-queue-any-perl didn't seem to help noticeably.

Comment: `Thread::Queue` is a `Perl` core module since version 5.8, so chances are that you have that module already. Another likely root cause for the original problem is a bug in `automake` version 1.15, please see my answer for details.

Comment: This just worked for me trying to compile automakte 1.16.3 using perl 5.16 on CentOS 7.