# ERROR: automake-native-1.15-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed

Tags: core-image, bitbake

I am trying to build an image "core-image-apd-level" but while running the command "**bitbake core-image-apd-level**", I am getting the mentioned error.

This is the complete log file data:

Log data follows:

| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile

| NOTE: make -j 4

| : && /bin/mkdir -p doc && { PATH='/home/manoj/apd-source/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.15-r0/build/t/wrap:'$PATH && export PATH; } && /usr/bin/perl ../automake-1.15/doc/help2man --output=doc/automake-1.15.1 automake-1.15

| help2man: can't get `--help' info from automake-1.15

| Try `--no-discard-stderr' if option outputs to stderr

| Makefile:3687: recipe for target 'doc/automake-1.15.1' failed

| make: *** [doc/automake-1.15.1] Error 255

| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.

| ERROR: oe_runmake failed

| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/manoj/apd-source/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.15-r0/temp/log.do_compile.26476)

ERROR: Task 552 (virtual:native:/home/manoj/apd-source/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/automake/automake_1.15.bb, do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 98 tasks of which 93 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Waiting for 0 running tasks to finish:

Summary: 1 task failed:
  virtual:native:/home/manoj/apd-source/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/automake/automake_1.15.bb, do_compile

Summary: There was 1 WARNING message shown.

Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.

*How do I get past this error?*

Answer (score 1):

I have found 2 solutions when the issue occurs, you can either:

1.[downgrade perl or upgrade automake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39141038/unable-to-build-gnu-automake)

or

2.[modify make file](http://www.programmersought.com/article/3712239655/)
while I chose later one for automake is less likey changed, 
and less impact, comparing to perl for me.

Hope it helps.